# Simple 3D smoke algorithm for particle emitter in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl

I need to create a simple particle emitter to achieve somekind of a smoke-like effect. 
I need help with the algorithm that should do something like this:

*Create X amount of particles in a frame with lifetime L

*Define the velocity for each individual particle in a frame

Is there some nice mathemtical algorithm available for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most I've seen simply has an emission velocity at emitter level, then when you emit the particle you pick a velocity vector which slightly deviates from the emitter both in direction & length. More advanced solutions makes it volumetric by simulating it as fluids instead. Googling volumetric smoke will likely turn up a ton of tips on this.

Answer (score 0):

I found this complicated example - [fluidsim](https://github.com/prideout/fluidsim).
And another one on simple C without OpenGL, you can find algorithm inside, [check it](https://code.google.com/p/smoke3d/)